# Entity Framework Ошибка при попытке получение данных

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой что при выборке всех данных из таблицы "client" базы "new_mord" выбивает такую ошибку: "MySqlException: Table 'new_mord.new_mord.client' doesn't exist", то есть он дублирует название БД. Как подключал модель вы увидите на скриншотах ниже.

Код BaseModel.context.cs:

```
private static new_mordEntities _context;
public static new_mordEntities GetContext()
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context = new new_mordEntities();
            return _context;
        }
```

Как пытаюсь получить данные:

```
var tmp = new_mordEntities.GetContext().clients.ToList();
```

Файл App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="new_mordEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BaseModel.csdl|res://*/BaseModel.ssdl|res://*/BaseModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=Qwe123456;database=new_mord&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

[image: Как я создаю модель]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы счастливый человек, можете EDM пользоваться. Этот инструмент всё хуже и хуже работает в net core - прямо вынуждают переходить на Code First. Последний раз пришлось руками модель ковырять. :(

Comment: @AK, кх-м, а в `EF core` разве когда-то была возможность работать с EDM? По-моему от нее избавились еще в самой первой версии, а в последней версии так и Database First не рекомендуют использовать (это я в одном из курсов pluralsight услышал).

Comment: `Table 'new_mord.new_mord.client' doesn't exist"` а вы проверили? Такой таблицы в БД действительно нет?

Comment: @Bulson посмотрел проект. Да, это ещё на EF6 проект, легаси медлееенно переписываемое по кусочкам чтобы потом перепрыгнуть на core. Значит ещё и придётся от emdx отказываться. Но хотя формально в EF6.3 - 6.4 это ещё поддерживается, но багов столько уже с новым csproj что приходится всё чаще руками корректировать файлы.

Comment: Решил проблему с помощью метода тыка, в общем: установил последнюю версию mysql.data.EntityFrameWork подключил модель, после понизил версию EntityFramework до версии 6.2.0. Я думал это из-за того что пакет EntityFrameWork.RU максимальной версии 6.2.0 и он как то конфликтует.